# How do I fix the global abiword spellcheck language?

Tags: spell-checking, abiword

I have Ubuntu 16.10 with abiword (3.0) installed. It seems to have a global default spell check language of UK English (keeps trying to correct "behavior" to "behaviour"). How do I switch this to US English? None of the info for this on the abiword website seems applicable.

Comment: I neither use `abiword` or have it installed, but reading the `man` page (`man abiword`) shows that there is a "profile" in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME/abiword/profile`. Check there

Comment: I found this profile but it has nothing about default language. I tried man abiword and learned that abiword uses enchant. I tried man enchant, and it mentioned a file called enchant.ordering, but this file seems to be for specifying where to find the dictionary for a given language. So what I still need is a way to specify the default spellcheck language.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
Open a new document, change the language in the spell check to the preferred one:
Tools -> set language

Save this document as a template called "normal.awt" in
/home/yourname
/.config/abiword/templates/
thereafter every new document will open in your preferred language.

Greetings from Sweden